# iPhone not reacting when connected to electricity

Tags: iphone, charging, touchscreen

today in the morning when my phone woke me up i couldn't turn off the alarm clock (you just have to swipe to the left and everything is fine). It didn't respond to any touch gesture till i disconnected the phone from the power supply. After that everything went well! 
What was that? Could it be that the phone got too much power??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of cable are you using? I've seen similar behaviour with

1. Poor quality third-party Lightning cables
2. A poor quality USB charger

I think there must be some form of 'leakage' which affects the working of the touch screen when using some sub-standard chargers/cables. I'd suggest either changing your cable or charger and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The cable is 3rd-Party but i've never had issues with that. But after i took a look at the USB-Plug i figured out that it's lose inside, so maybe that one is the problem though it's apple original :) Thank you again!